# How to send events in one button form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging, material-ui

I need to send event to backend with isVerified true/false depending on last condition
but i can either have just one button form.
How can i do it?

```
    <form onSubmit={(ev) => this.submit(ev, 'isVerified')}>
                                <ButtonWrapper gutterTop>
                                    <Button
                                        variant='contained'
                                        type='submit'
                                        color='secondary'
                                        size='large'
                                        disabled={this.state.isSubmitting}
                                    >Verify</Button>
                                </ButtonWrapper>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and  onClick call that function inside that function you can trigger multiple events / multiple things as you want.